# Symfony 3.2 Project on Azure

Tags: php, azure, web-config, symfony, azure-web-app-service

I am having a difficult time setting up the web.config file for a symfony project on Azure. I followed the steps in [Deoploying to MS Azure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/azure-website.html#configure-the-web-server) , but cannot access anything other than what is served at `app-name.azurewebsites.net`. So if i try to access `app-name.azurewebsites.net/admin` I get

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable`

Clearing cache did not solve the issue.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="BlockAccessToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="/web/*" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app.php/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Update to this.** The only way I can get to other routes is by having `app.php` in the url. EX: `app-name.azurewebsites.net/app.php/admin` . what is wrong with current config rewrite so I can have it as `app-name.azurewebsites.net/admin`
Any guidance to solve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `web.config` file to achieve this, you can add `web/app.php` into *Default documents* in **Application settings** via the Azure portal.

To do that, you can follow the following steps.

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com) and navigate to your App Service.
2. Click on **Application settings**, then scroll to *Default documents* section.
3. Add `web/app.php` into *Default documents* and click **Save** Button.

Here the picture:

[image]

---

### Edit:

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Once the *Default documents* have been configured, we no longer need to append `web/app.php` in the URL.

[image]

---

I have tested the `web.config` file which you provide and it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. trying this method and removing web.config from root directory is leading to a new error. `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` when viewing what is my home page. Doing this method requires app.php to be in the url to access any route.

Comment: I have updated my reply by adding the folder structure. Add what does your folder structure look like?

Comment: folder structure is exactly like yours. I left the web unchanged other than adding folders for js, css, and images. the home page works fine without having to have app.php in the url. if i want to go to another route such as `admin/user/create` , the url must be `app.php/admin/user/create`

Comment: Curious why i still have a problem. One difference is they I am not using annotations for routing. I appreciate your time on this. Since this is a school project, i've gotten to the point where pretty urls are not as important. Since web config works for you, I will accept the answer.